# Выбивает ошибку Exception has occurred: TypeError __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Tags: python, discord

Выбивает ошибку
**Exception has occurred: TypeError **init**() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
File "D:\VS code\Microsoft VS Code\keyllard.py", line 6, in 
client = commands.Bot( command_prefix = 'y.' )**

при коде

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot( command_prefix = 'y.' ) 


@client.event 

async def on_ready():
    print ( 'Bot connected' )

@client.command( pass_context = True )

async def test( ctx ):
    await ctx.send( 'confirm' )


client.run( '***' )
```

Comment: нужен перевод фразы `missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'`?

Comment: перевод ясен, не ясно, что написать, чтобы работало

Answer (score 1):

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= 'y.', intents=intents)
```